# start and queue coming at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the queue notification not to come, even though I open a song for the first time on the channel in discord bot, what should I do? play only notification on the first song I opened. Then the queue should come when I add different songs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbCph.png)

you can access play code here: https://complete-sixth-scowl.glitch.me/play.js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put your code directly inside your question whenever possible.

Comment: try to check queue length before sending message. If it is first song of queue don't send queue message